# How to drop multiple streams with one query?

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I want to drop multiple streams, drop is working for single stream only.This ksql query:

```
DROP STREAMS stream1, streams2;
```

is not working. what is the other way to achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried `DROP STREAM stream1, streams2?`

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous i have tried this...its not working.

Comment: Any help there @GiorgosMyrianthous ?

Answer (score 1):

ksqlDB, as of the current version v0.10, does not support dropping multiple streams with a single statement. You would need to execute one statement per stream, i.e.

```
DROP STREAMS stream1; 
DROP STREAMS stream2;
```